# SKIP LOCKED DATA Syntax issue in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to execute simple select query with SKIP LOCKED DATA
but getting syntax error. Below is the sample query

```
SELECT ELEMENT FROM WORKQUEUE
  WHERE PRIORITY = '1' AND STATUS='OPEN' 
  SKIP LOCKED DATA;
```

Got error as below

```
    DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SKIP;
<query_expression>;END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=3.61.86
```

But as per [documents](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/perf/src/tpc/db2z_useskiplockeddata.html) it is valid query. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What's your db2 platform?

Comment: It's DB2/AIX64  platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are not using `Db2 for z/OS 10.0.0`

I suspect you are using e.g `Db2 11.1`  and you need a manual page from that Db2 platform such as

"Evaluate uncommitted data through lock deferral" - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0011218.html

because Db2 for Linux, Unix and Windows does not support the `SKIP LOCKED DATA` clause directly